# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize my secondary USB monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, acer

I got an ASUS MB168B external monitor from an acquaintance, but I cannot get my Ubuntu 18.04 to detect it as a monitor.

If I go to

> Settings -> Devices -> Displays

Ubuntu lists only the built-in display. `xrandr` only displays Screen0 (and HDMI):

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
...
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lsusb` shows that USB device is there:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
```

I have installed the displaylink driver version 5.1.26.
And I've got an Acer Swift 3 with *Intel UHD Graphics 620*:

```
$ lspci -k
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I've read tens of discussions, but at this point, I have no idea what else to do, so your help is appreciated.

(user level: relatively n00b)

Comment: I have displaylink driver version 5.1.26 installed. (How can I check if it's properly installed - I understood next to nothing about drivers on Windows and I understand even less on Ubuntu...)

Comment: I got the driver from https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

I followed the instructions on how to install and I did not encounter any problems when installing.